# Entropy task -- discover illness persons

Tags: probability, combinatorics, entropy

There are 11 people in group, 2 of them are ill without any visibility of it. New way to test people can say have one person illness or not, but it works only for one person, one test == one person. What's the minimum guaranteed number of this tests need to be done to discover all illness persons?

Comment: What does "the minimum guaranteed number" mean?

Comment: it's minimum number of tests to identify this 2 persons

Comment: Does the test have 100% accuracy rate?

Comment: Yes, 100% accuracy

Comment: Sounds like if you select people randomly there will still be cases where you will need to test up to 9 people, if they all come back negative then you know the remaining 2 are the ill ones. 

Unless "guaranteed" has some definition like correct 95% of the time.

Comment: @BenedictW.J.Irwin: That’s not the worst case: what if you’re tested $9$ people and found just one of the two who are ill?

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Good point! So the answer is 10.

Comment: @BenedictW.J.Irwin: thank you!

Comment: What's the relation with entropy? It could have been related to entropy, if the test could be done on mixture of bloods of some people, otherwise it is not related to entropy.